# error in getFollowing(); the application hangs

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

The application hangs, in these two parts. And it does not let you start the application.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mFollowing = new ArrayList<>();
    mPhotos = new ArrayList<>();

    getFollowing(); /* <= error */

    return view;
}

private void getFollowing(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getFollowing: searching for following");

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_following))  
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()); /* <= error */

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: "+ 
        singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue());

                mFollowing.add(singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue().toString());
            }
            mFollowing.add(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
            //get the photos
            getPhotos();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This isn't C — is it C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "The application hangs" while you also state "does not let you start the application"? Those two things sound like an impossible contradiction.

Comment: I edited (to fix what seemed an impossible C Syntax). So the seemingly  still impossible syntax might be my fault... In that case please take my apology and just make sure that the code is exactly like your code, only with correct comments indicating the error lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think this might be Java. Note the enhanced for loop syntax, and the use of `ArrayList`, as well as `@` syntax for attributes